# Reading multiple bytes from file and storing them for comparison in C++

Tags: c++, binary

I want to binary read a photo in 1460 bytes increments and compare consecutive packets for corrupted transmission. I have a python script that i wrote and want to translate in C++, however I'm not sure that what I intend to use is correct.

```
for i in range(0, fileSize-1):
    buff=f.read(1460) // buff stores a packet of 1460 bytes where f is the opened file
    secondPacket=''
    for j in buff:
        secondPacket+="{:02x}".format(j)
    if(secondPacket==firstPacket):
        print(f'Packet {i+1} identical with {i}')
    firstPacket=secondPacket
```

I have found `int fseek ( FILE * stream, long int offset, int origin );` but it's unclear if it reads the first byte that is located `offset` away from `origin` or everything in between.

Thanks for clarifications.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>

std::array<char, 1460> firstPacket;
std::array<char, 1460> secondPacket;
int i=0;

int main() {
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("photo.jpg", std::ios::binary);

    while (file.read(firstPacket.data(), firstPacket.size())){
        ++i;
        if (firstPacket==secondPacket)
            std::cout<<"Packet "<<i<<" is a copy of packet "<<i-1<<std::endl;
        memcpy(&secondPacket, &firstPacket, firstPacket.size());
    }
    std::cout<<i; //tested to check if i iterate correctly
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code i have so far which doesn't work.

Comment: according to this [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek) `fseek` just put you "start read" the pos according to the offset and origin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fseek
```

doesn't read, it just moves the point where the next read operation should begin. If you read the file from start to end you don't need this.

To read binary data you want the aptly named [`std::istream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read). You can use it like this wih a fixed size buffer:

```
// char is one byte, could also be uint8_t, but then you would need a cast later on
std::array<char, 1460> bytes; 


while(myInputStream.read(bytes.data(), bytes.size())) {
    // do work with the read data
}
```

Comment: Hey i wrote this http://cpp.sh/6ecpn  but it seems to not execute the loop at all. What might be wrong?

Comment: The link seems to be broken :/ One reason might be that the stream was not opened at all, for example if the file does not exist. You can check it with something like `if(!myInputStream) { /* error */` after opening.

Comment: Have edited my question to include the code i wrote. Sorry for the belated response.

Comment: Yep, as I said, check if the file was opened successfully. And keep in mind that the path is relative to the directory where your program is executed, maybe that's the problem.